# postfix deletes mail after it has been received

Tags: postfix-mta

I am stuck with my postfix settings. I've managed to let it work outside its machine. I have a vps with Ubuntu.

Now I've some virtual email address. I can send email to it but after it then Postfix will delete it right after it has been sent.

Below here are the details.

> Nov 30 21:39:22 lendev postfix/virtual[32555]: 961E44A1128: to=, relay=virtual, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
>
> Nov 30 21:39:22 lendev postfix/qmgr[32467]: 961E44A1128: removed

Postfix works with mysql database.

I hope you guys can help me with it.

Comment: This is a Q&A site for programming questions, and I'm not seeing how this is on-topic here.

Comment: Well my question is why its deleting my mails that I send with sendmail with php. But after its send postfix deletes it automatically. And how do I turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

The log excerpt you posted means this:

1. postfix delivered the mail to a mailbox using the virtual delivery agent (see "man 8 virtual")
2. after delivery to the mailbox, Postfix removed it's queue file (since the status was "sent", thus the transaction is finished)

Meaning: The mail was delivered someplace (as defined in virtual_mailbox_base) in the local file system.